# How and what kind of database can be used to do Banking Transaction tasks in real time like withdrawal of money?

Tags: mysql, mongodb, transactions, couchdb

I am in a dilemma of what NonSql databases to use for transactions like bank transactions i.e. withdrawal, deposit while keeping the relation ship intact between the customers,customer account, product paid for, bank charges and many other entities.

Do i stick to Sql, which is a bit slow for large records or i find a NonSql database which is much faster but trouble is with relations and database transaction.

I need an answer from any expert working with this dilemma.

Comment: MongoDB might be the best NoSQL database for dealing with relationship and all the stuff similar to SQL. I would not even consider CouchDB(since you tagged it) because it would be so messy to deal with those relationships. Although, banking databases rely on a lot of relationships. NoSQL is good when you have denormalized data and schemaless data. Even if SQL might be a bit slower, It's still fast enough and way more safe for banking. So I would say to stick to SQL.  Good luck my friend

Comment: Thanks @AlexisCôté for you wonderful feedback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

an per Alex comment, NoSql could be not a 100% suit, but you can think about NewSQL solutions like VoltDB, which has a good approach to handle high volume of transactions and process reporting queries too.

[see VoltDB comparison](https://www.voltdb.com/blog/nosql-vs-newsql-choosing-right-tool)

Comment: Have You used VoltDB before for a massive data? Like lets say 10,000,000 records and you are using it in production? Please help me understand.

Comment: unfortunately didn't had a chance as in my workplace such a solution is not required. there is other newSql solution that you can test for free `NuoDb` http://www.nuodb.com/dev-center

Comment: Thanks, let me check it out.